# Usage of とする in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I had some doubts of the usage of とする in this sentence "計画や希望などを現実のものとすること。" Does it mean "to assume something" in this specific case?
Moreover is the の after 実現 a nominalizer, assuming that in highly formal contexts する　can be omitted?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> 計画や希望などを現実のものとすること

just means

> to make one's plans and hopes into a reality

現実のもの means "something which is actualized".  の here is not a nominalizer.  の is just the genative particle which often can be translated into English as "which is..."

AをBとする is a fixed expression meaning "to make A B".

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your explanation. In this other sentence, what would be the meaning of とする instead? "その程度をもって限度とすることを示す。"

Comment: It's the same usage, but the context is missing.  Context would tell us what "A" is.  Here "B" is 限度.  Without further context, I'd scan this as "It indicates that the limit be set according to the degree".  Context would greatly help in making a better translation though.